# what is the use of ngTouch dependency in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-touch

I am a beginner in AngularJs programming,and I am not able to figure out what is the use of ngTouch in angularjs? I am asking this question because I had made a small website, which I assumed that will not work fine on tabs without the ngTouch module,so i used it there,but due to some errors,i removed its dependency from module, and it is working as expected, and I also ran into a lot of issues on android touch device because of ngTouch being used.so what is the use of ngTouch then?

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngTouch):

> The ngTouch module provides touch events and other helpers for
>   touch-enabled devices. The implementation is based on jQuery Mobile
>   touch event handling

Here is a [good explanation](http://onehungrymind.com/build-sweet-angularjs-photo-slider-pt-2-ngtouch/) on how it works with an example.